# Running the Android app without TitleBar

Tags: android, android-titlebar

As by default, the application name is appearing on one label like TextView. How do i remove my titlebar permanently for my application?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use below code for that -

```
<activity android:name="YourActivityname" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />
```

If you want the full screen of your device you can use below code -

```
<activity android:name="YourActivityname" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
```

And, also refer [Developer's Site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#theme)

Comment: The Fullscreen also used for me.

Answer (score 3):

That is a setting based on the activity in your android manifest file.

Use the No Title Bar theme for your activity.

```
<activity android:name="MyActivityName" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />
```